# Removing rows by count from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

With the following DataFrame...

```
                     line_date line_track  line_race  c1pos
 horse_name                                                
 Grand Cicero       2013-03-10         GP          9      9
 Clever Story       2013-09-13        BEL          7      7
 Distorted Dream    2013-10-04        BEL          4      2
 Distorted Dream    2013-09-13        BEL          7      5
 Distorted Dream    2013-04-27        BEL          6      2
 Distorted Dream    2012-10-24        BEL          4      2
 Distorted Dream    2012-09-12        BEL          2      3
 Distorted Dream    2012-06-30        BEL          8      4
 Distorted Dream    2012-06-09        BEL          2      4
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-10-13        BEL          5      5
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-08-29        SAR          7      6
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-05-27        BEL          6      5
 In the Dark        2013-10-13        BEL          5      7
 In the Dark        2013-09-22        BEL          5      7
 In the Dark        2013-08-03        SAR          2      7
 In the Dark        2012-11-24        AQU          3      7
 In the Dark        2012-10-18        BEL          6      6
 Bred to Boss       2013-10-26        PRX          3      5
 Bred to Boss       2013-10-06        PRX          6      3
 Bred to Boss       2012-08-18        SAR          4      1
```

...the index is set to `horse_name`. I need to "trim" each of these to a certain number. For example, "Distorted Dream" has seven records. I need to reduce all of those with more than say three records down to three, so it produces a DataFrame like the one below. Is there a quick an easy way to do this?

```
                     line_date line_track  line_race  c1pos
 horse_name                                                
 Grand Cicero       2013-03-10         GP          9      9
 Clever Story       2013-09-13        BEL          7      7
 Distorted Dream    2013-10-04        BEL          4      2
 Distorted Dream    2013-09-13        BEL          7      5
 Distorted Dream    2013-04-27        BEL          6      2
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-10-13        BEL          5      5
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-08-29        SAR          7      6
 Mr. O'Leary        2013-05-27        BEL          6      5
 In the Dark        2013-10-13        BEL          5      7
 In the Dark        2013-09-22        BEL          5      7
 In the Dark        2013-08-03        SAR          2      7
 Bred to Boss       2013-10-26        PRX          3      5
 Bred to Boss       2013-10-06        PRX          6      3
 Bred to Boss       2012-08-18        SAR          4      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it so often is, `groupby` to the rescue!  It's worthwhile reading through the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) as there are lots of useful tricks one can pull.

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0, sort=False, as_index=False).head(3)
                  line_date line_track  line_race  c1pos
horse_name                                              
Grand Cicero     2013-03-10         GP          9      9
Clever Story     2013-09-13        BEL          7      7
Distorted Dream  2013-10-04        BEL          4      2
Distorted Dream  2013-09-13        BEL          7      5
Distorted Dream  2013-04-27        BEL          6      2
Mr. O'Leary      2013-10-13        BEL          5      5
Mr. O'Leary      2013-08-29        SAR          7      6
Mr. O'Leary      2013-05-27        BEL          6      5
In the Dark      2013-10-13        BEL          5      7
In the Dark      2013-09-22        BEL          5      7
In the Dark      2013-08-03        SAR          2      7
Bred to Boss     2013-10-26        PRX          3      5
Bred to Boss     2013-10-06        PRX          6      3
Bred to Boss     2012-08-18        SAR          4      1
```

Or, if you want the last 3:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0, sort=False, as_index=False).tail(3)
```

(The `sort=False` is there just to preserve the original horse order; if you don't care about that, you can drop it.)

You could also sort on the `line_date` column (safer to convert it to `datetime` first, but `YYYY-MM-DD` strings will sort correctly as they are) and select either the first or last three chronologically using the same `head`/`tail` method.

Comment: I didn't even think to look to `groupby` ... I was stuck in the mindset of slicing and never went that direction. Thank you!